Window border and shadow on ubuntu 24.04
On Ubuntu 24.04 with Wayland.
I want to add shadow on or border on windows.
How do I do it?

may be related https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtbase-opensource-src/+bug/2063332

What I have found-out is that if I add
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb 
border and shadow appears...

You can answer your own question and after a short period accept it see this help page

edit /usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css

this should do it:
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks gnome-shell-extension-manager

then install "Blur My Shell" extension from:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3193/blur-my-shell/
or from source:
git clone https://github.com/aunetx/blur-my-shell
cd blur-my-shell
make install

then
git clone https://github.com/vinceliuice/WhiteSur-gtk-theme.git
cd WhiteSur-gtk-theme
./install.sh
Apply theme using GNOME Tweaks > Appearance.
Alternative: Use Mutter Rounded for rounded corners with shadows:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5237/rounded-window-corners/
or download release
https://github.com/yilozt/rounded-window-corners/releases
then:
gnome-extensions install rounded-window-corners@yilozt.shell-extension.zip


to install "blur my shell" you need to install GNOME Shell integration in your browser. Tweaks is required for changing the Themes. You might wish to make that clearer in your answer

Thanks, I will test this in the morning...
